# Is there an easy way to find out a tweet I re-tweeted?

Tags: twitter, retweet

I vaguely remember there was a "retweets" link somewhere in an older version of the interface, but it's gone now (?).

Is there a simple way to find a tweet I've re-tweeted (that I found when it was re-tweeted by someone I follow)? A search query I'm missing perhaps? I'd prefer not to resort to the API (I'm lazy), but if that's the only way... ;)

Comment: You can search using `include:retweets`, but I can't figure out how to get *only* retweets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a list of your retweets at http://favstar.fm/users/yrizos/retweeted, there is no way to search through them and they only show the most recent tweets.

A non-web solution would be to use https://github.com/sferik/t, a Twitter CLI

example

```
t retweets stackexchange
```

[image: Retweets from StackExchange Twitter account]

Shows retweets made by user "stackexchange"

or `t search retweets "stackoverflow"`

(Search my account for any retweets I made with the word "stackoverflow"

[image: Search by retweets for the phrase stackoverflow]

Comment: Thanks! I found what I was looking for, although that favstar thingy sure looks ugly.